# User inputted query for reddit search API

Tags: javascript, json, api, search, reddit

Now that I can utilize the search function for reddit's API, I want the user to input their own query. I'm new to javascript and I think the problem with my code is that the API search function is being ran before the user even inputs the query.

HTML:

```
<div id="site-content">
<form name="RedditSearch">
    Enter your query:
    <input type="text" name="query" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('search').click()"/>
    <input type="button" id="search" value="Search" onclick="searchquery();" />
</form>    
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var container = $('#site-content')
function searchquery()
{
 var query = document.RedditSearch.query.value;
}
 $.getJSON("http://www.reddit.com/search.json?q=" + query, function(data) {
  $.each(data.data.children, function(i,item){
    var title = item.data.title
    var post = '<div>'+title+'</div>'
    container.append(post)        

});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, it appears that your getJSON query is executed when the page loads. At that time, the user hasn't input anything yet, so it is executed too early.

You need to add an event listener which will detect user input, and then perform the AJAX call to the reddit API.

Assuming your user inputs his keywords in a text area, you could use `.change()`.

You can fine more informations here : http://api.jquery.com/category/events/‎  or here http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_change.asp

Example in your case : http://jsfiddle.net/2ECG6/1/

Comment: Thanks for quick response; I'm looking at the example at the page you sent me and I'm still having trouble determining where to include the change function. I also don't even see how the function on the example is connecting with the "sweets" list of options, since the JS does not seem to call it.. I'm assuming I would include the change() infront of my function(data) that runs the reddit API, but how does that know what variable to look for a change?

Comment: @user3253373 i added a W3school link which provides more information and a very good example of use !

Comment: Sorry for my horrible incompetence of JS, but when you refer to $(user-input), are you referring to my searchquery() function? Considering that is the function that pulls the query variable from my HTML input box.. and then would i run my $.getJSON nested inside of the searchquery() function?

Comment: Nvm, your fiddle answered all my question. Really appreciate the help!!

Comment: You are welcome ! I updated the fiddle, as it wasn't correctly reading the value of the input textarea, now it works fine.

Comment: One last question - so I got it to successfully work using your change method, but I'm trying to run the function redditsearch() when the button is clicked, as opposed to looking for change in the text box. The function doesn't seem to run at all when I click the button since I put an alert in there. Any ideas?
http://jsfiddle.net/elliotmersch/pZ7Cn/

Comment: @user3253373 : You can simply use the click listener on the button. http://jsfiddle.net/pZ7Cn/2/